# JSON Array Not Serializing

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

For some reason, without error, the JsonSerializer in RestSharp is not Serializing the following data.

The returned object has all data, except the Calls array is NULL. 
See Output: http://puu.sh/hCsy9/5353cd7e02.png

> {   "api_id": "c7b1346a-f345-11e4-9335-22000ac50cb2",   "meta": {
>       "limit": 20,
>       "next": "/v1/Account/MAOTAWNJFHYZM5NTA5ZD/Call/?limit=20&offset=20",
>       "offset": 0,
>       "previous": null,
>       "total_count": 3072   },   "objects": [
>       {
>         "bill_duration": 10,
>         "billed_duration": 60,
>         "call_direction": "outbound",
>         "call_duration": 10,
>         "call_uuid": "582fcfe2-f337-11e4-a997-ff7e66a0ec10",
>         "end_time": "2015-05-05 10:59:59-04:00",
>         "from_number": null,
>         "parent_call_uuid": "57b02c7e-f337-11e4-a957-ff7e66a0ec10",
>         "resource_uri": "/v1/Account/MAOTAWNJFHYZM5NTA5ZD/Call/582fcfe2-f337-11e4-a997-ff7e66a0ec10/",
>         "to_number": "17168072289",
>         "total_amount": "0.01200",
>         "total_rate": "0.01200"
>       },
>       {
>         "bill_duration": 10,
>         "billed_duration": 60,
>         "call_direction": "inbound",
>         "call_duration": 10,
>         "call_uuid": "57b02c7e-f337-11e4-a957-ff7e66a0ec10",
>         "end_time": "2015-05-05 10:59:59-04:00",
>         "from_number": "sip:225@127.0.0.1",
>         "parent_call_uuid": null,
>         "resource_uri": "/v1/Account/MAOTAWNJFHYZM5NTA5ZD/Call/57b02c7e-f337-11e4-a957-ff7e66a0ec10/",
>         "to_number": "sip:elastix150502112926@phone.plivo.com",
>         "total_amount": "0.00300",
>         "total_rate": "0.00300"
>       }       ] }

```
public class GetAllCallsResponse : PlivoResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "meta")]
    public GetAllCallsMeta Meta { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "objects")]
    public List<datas> Calls { get; set; }
}

 [DataContract]
public class datas
{
    [DataMember]
    public int bill_duration { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public int billed_duration { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string call_direction { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public int call_duration { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string call_uuid { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string end_time { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string from_number { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string parent_call_uuid { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string resource_uri { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string to_number { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string total_amount { get; set; }
     [DataMember]
    public string total_rate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DeserializeAs attribute:

```
public class GetAllCallsResponse : PlivoResponse
{

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "meta")]
    public GetAllCallsMeta Meta { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "objects")]
    public List<datas> Calls { get; set; }
}


public class datas
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "bill_duration")]
    public int bill_duration { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "billed_duration")]
    public int billed_duration { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "call_direction")]
    public string call_direction { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "call_duration")]
    public int call_duration { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "call_uuid")]
    public string call_uuid { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "end_time")]
    public string end_time { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "from_number")]
    public string from_number { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "parent_call_uuid")]
    public string parent_call_uuid { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "resource_uri")]
    public string resource_uri { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "to_number")]
    public string to_number { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "total_amount")]
    public string total_amount { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "total_rate")]
    public string total_rate { get; set; }
}
```